# Apply workflow changes to every project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I recently started using TFS 2012 for bug tracking. Yesterday I was assigned a bug that ended up being not a bug at all, so I followed [this guide](http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/How-to-mark-a-bug-as-Rejected-with-TFS-.aspx) to add a new custom resolved reason.

This worked fine, and I closed my bug successfully with my new "Not a Bug" reason.

However, today I received another bug (on a different project) that was also not a bug. When I went to resolve it, my new "not a bug reason" did not appear. In retrospect this makes sense given that I only modified the workflow for my old project (Project A), and not Project B.

I could obviously just change the workflow manually again for Project B, but I'd like to have this custom reason (and others eventually) available by default on every project. Given that there are a few dozen projects in source control it would take quite some time to do this manually. I didn't see any way to edit a generic workflow, I always had to select one under a specific project.

**Is there any way to make workflow changes that apply to every project by default?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic switch that allows you to deploy your changes to more than one team project.

1. You could create a batch file with the [`witadmin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) command line to import it to each team project, then just run that for each change.
2. You could create a build definition to deploy your changes. Details for TFS 2010 are on [Ed Squared's blog](http://www.edsquared.com/2010/06/18/Deploying+Process+Template+Changes+Using+TFS+2010+Build.aspx). I think this needs updating for TFS 2012 though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into doing that.